# Multidimensional array made in c++

Tags: c++

In some of my past c++ projects, I would sometimes end up having to use a multidimensional array. However, I often would spend more than a needed amount of time on how to store the multidimensional array.so as a result, I decided to create a multidimensional array c++ class.
here is the code

mdarray.hh

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::uint64_t N>
class multidimensional_array {
  std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>> _data{0};

  template <typename Size1, typename... Sizes>
  void _resize(const Size1 &size1, const Sizes &... sizes) {
    _data.resize(size1);
    for (auto &item : _data) {
      item.resize(sizes...);
    }
  }
  template <typename Size1>
  void _resize(const Size1 &size1) {
    _data.resize(size1);
  }

 public:
  // iterators
  using iterator =
      typename std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>>::iterator;
  using const_iterator =
      typename std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>>::const_iterator;

  // constructers
  multidimensional_array() = default;
  virtual ~multidimensional_array() = default;

  template <typename... Sizes>
  multidimensional_array(const Sizes &... sizes) {
    resize(sizes...);
  }
  multidimensional_array(
      const std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>> &Items)
      : _data(Items) {}

  // access to data
 public:
  std::vector<T> data() { return _data; }
  T *raw_data() { return _data.begin()->raw_data(); }

  multidimensional_array<T, N - 1> &operator[](std::uint64_t index) {
    return _data.at(index);
  }

 public:
  // access to size
  std::uint64_t size() { return _data.size(); }
  template <typename... Sizes>
  void resize(const Sizes &... sizes) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(sizes) <= N,
                  "the number of parameters is more the number of dimensions");
    _resize(sizes...);
  }
  template <typename Size>
  void resize(const Size &size1) {
    _resize(size1);
  }
  // helper functions

 public:
  void fill(iterator first, iterator last, const T &item) {
    for (; first != last; first++) {
      first->fill(first->begin(), first->end(), item);
    }
  }
  void fill(const T &item) { fill(begin(), end(), item); }
  template <typename F>
  void for_each(F &&function) {
    for (auto &item : _data) {
      item.for_each(function);
    }
  }

  // iterators
 public:
  iterator begin() noexcept { return _data.begin(); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return _data.cbegin(); }
  iterator end() noexcept { return _data.end(); }
  const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return _data.cend(); }
};

// class for 1d array
template <typename T>
class multidimensional_array<T, 1> {
 private:
  std::vector<T> _data{0};

 public:
  // iterators
  using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

  // constructers
  multidimensional_array(const std::uint64_t &size) : _data(size){};
  multidimensional_array(const std::vector<T> &Items) : _data(Items){};

  multidimensional_array() = default;
  virtual ~multidimensional_array() = default;

  template <typename Size>
  multidimensional_array(const Size &size1) {
    resize(size1);
  }

  // access to data
 public:
  std::vector<T> &data() { return _data; }
  T *raw_data() { return _data.data(); }

  T &operator[](std::uint64_t index) { return _data.at(index); }
  // helper functions
 public:
  void fill(iterator first, iterator last, const T &item) {
    for (; first != last; first++) {
      *first = item;
    }
  }
  void fill(const T &item) { fill(begin(), end(), item); }
  template <typename F>
  void for_each(F &&function) {
    for (auto &item : _data) {
      function(item);
    }
  }

 public:
  // access to size
  std::uint64_t size() { return _data.size(); }
  template <typename Size>
  void resize(const Size &size1) {
    _data.resize(size1);
  }

  // iterator
 public:
  iterator begin() noexcept { return _data.begin(); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return _data.cbegin(); }
  iterator end() noexcept { return _data.end(); }
  const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return _data.cend(); }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>> _data{0};
```

What does this line do? (Possible hint: `{0}` is a braced initializer sequence consisting of a single `int`, and `int` is implicitly convertible to `multidimensional_array<T, N-1>`. Or is this an anti-hint? Can you tell, without asking a compiler?)

If you want to create an empty vector, just use `vector`'s default constructor:

```
std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>> _data;
```

or convert from an empty initializer-list:

```
std::vector<multidimensional_array<T, N - 1>> _data = {};
```

See ["The Knightmare of Initialization in C++."](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/18/knightmare-of-initialization/)

---

```
virtual ~multidimensional_array() = default;
```

Yikes! Why does this class need a vtable? Are you intending to inherit from it? Please don't!

---

```
  template <typename Size1, typename... Sizes>
  void _resize(const Size1 &size1, const Sizes &... sizes) {
    _data.resize(size1);
    for (auto &item : _data) {
      item.resize(sizes...);
    }
  }
  template <typename Size1>
  void _resize(const Size1 &size1) {
    _data.resize(size1);
  }
```

If you're allowed to use C++17 `if constexpr`, then you can write this without the "recursion", as:

```
template<class... Sizes>
void _resize(size_t head, Sizes... tail) {
    _data.resize(head);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) != 0) {
        for (auto&& elt : _data) {
            elt.resize(tail...);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
template <typename... Sizes>
multidimensional_array(const Sizes &... sizes) {
  resize(sizes...);
}
```

This constructor should be marked `explicit`. Otherwise, declarations like these will compile without complaint:

```
multidimensional_array<int, 1> a = 3;
multidimensional_array<int, 1> b {3};
```

In fact, you should probably forbid constructing a `multidimensional_array<T, N>` with any number of size parameters other than `N`. And in fact, to avoid the ambiguity of

```
multidimensional_array<int, 1> b {3};
```

entirely, let's just use a [factory method](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/21/factory-vs-conversion/) instead of a constructor. Result:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
class multidimensional_array {
public:
    template<class... Sizes,
             std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Sizes) == N, int> = 0,
             std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Sizes, size_t> && ...), int> = 0,
    >
    static multidimensional_array with_dimensions(Sizes... sizes) {
        multidimensional_array a;
        a.resize(sizes...);
        return a;
    }
    [...]
};

auto a1 = multidimensional_array<int, 1>::with_dimensions(2);
auto a2 = multidimensional_array<int, 1>{0, 0};
auto a3 = multidimensional_array<int, 2>::with_dimensions(3, 3);
```

Consider what should happen if the caller passes dimensions (0,0) or (-1,-1) or so on.

---

```
std::vector<T> data() { return _data; }
```

It is surprising that `data()` returns a *copy* of the data; that's not how `std::vector::data()` or `std::array::data()` work. I would expect to see also an overload of `data()` for const arrays:

```
std::vector<T>& data() { return _data; }
const std::vector<T>& data() const { return _data; }
```

...oh wait, except that *doesn't work at all*, because `_data` is not a `vector<T>`; it's a `vector<multidimensional_array<T,N-1>>`.

The moral of this story is that you should always test your code! C++ templates especially, because if you don't instantiate them, you'll never know if they even type-check at all.

```
T *raw_data() { return _data.begin()->raw_data(); }
```

This compiles, but is extremely scary, because it sounds (to me) like it ought to give a view onto a contiguous array of `(Sizes * ...)` objects of type `T`, but really it only gives a view onto the first linear "row" of the data; the rest of the data is stored somewhere else, non-contiguous with that row.

In fact, I would recommend that you not provide the `data()` accessor either, because the C++20 STL adds a notion of "contiguous container" which is triggered by seeing if the container has a plausible-looking `.data()` method (e.g. `vector`, `array`, `string`). Since your container is non-contiguous, you should probably avoid the word `.data()` — the same way you'd avoid the word `.begin()` for something that didn't return an iterator.

---

```
T &operator[](std::uint64_t index) { return _data.at(index); }
```

should have a `const` overload too. And you should almost certainly use `size_t`, not `uint64_t`, just to be idiomatic and to match the `size_type` of `std::vector`.

---

```
void for_each(F &&function)
```

Consider providing a `const` overload of `for_each`.

The STL-ese way of passing a callback is just `F function` — pass by value — because usually the function is just a stateless lambda or something equally cheap to copy. If the caller really wants pass-by-reference, all they have to do is wrap their function in `std::ref`.

---

Consider adding a `static_assert(N >= 2)` to the primary template. `N==0` should be a hard error.

Your repetition of `public:` is harmless but unidiomatic. We generally just have one big `public:` section and one big `private:` section (and personally I put them in that order, but reasonable people may vary on that).

---

Quick, off the top of your head, which parts of your design break when you instantiate `multidimensional_array<bool, 2>`? Which parts break *unsalvageably?*

Write unit tests! Pay particular attention to `const` — like, write a test that verifies that `a[3] = b[3]` compiles when `b` is const (but not when `a` is const).

Hmm, that reminds me: did you *want* `a[3] = b[3]` to compile? I should be able to assign the entire array at once `a = b`, and I should be able to assign one `T` object at a time `a[i][j] = t`, but should I also be able to assign one *row* at a time `a[i] = r`?

What about this?

```
auto mat = multidimensional_array<int, 2>::with_dimensions(3, 3);
mat[0].resize(2);

// Is `mat` now a 3x3 array with one corner cut out?
```